# SQL Database Deleted Flag and DeletedBy DeletedOn

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've added a history table to my database. Originally I added a Bit called Deleted and intended to update it to 1 if that row was ever deleted, otherwise each row is an update.

Then I was informed we need to log who deleted what when. So I added Nullable [DeletedBy]  [DeletedOn] fields. 
At this point I was wondering if this made my Deleted Bit redundant. You could simply query the table, checking where DeletedBy is not Null if you want to see which row is Deleted.

I intended to ask in this question which is better practice:

1. Having the extra Bit Column
2. Using the nullable columns that are already there, to Identify Deleted Rows

But I'm starting to think this is a preference thing. So instead my question is, which is more efficient? If this table gets massive, is there a performance gain to running:

```
    Select * from MyTable where [Deleted] = 1
```

over

```
    Select * from MyTable where [DeletedBy] is not null
```

Comment: Try it yourself and let us know. Add a few million dummy records and run the queries.

Comment: I think my boss would kill me if I added a few million rows to the work databases, but I guess I could install a trial of SQL server on my home box and give it a go there

Comment: @MikeyMouse:  Don't you have a test env? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Sure we do, it'd be worse than killing if I did it to live. The test server here is always short on space though

Comment: @MikeyMouse Ask for more space. How can they expect you to work without proper enviroments?

Comment: @asawyer I asked for version control and didn't get it... but hey, it's contracting, do what they say and keep your eye on the finish date

Comment: I dont see no difference performance wise.

Comment: You don't have an `UpdatedOn`, `UpdatedBy` set of columns?  If I was adding history logging, those would be the first columns added.  At which point, you use the bit to show whether it was the deletion, or a regular update.

Comment: If you are short on space, you're going to run out REALLY, REALLY fast by basically implementing an audit trail (i.e. this task). I'd give it a few days until you hose your dev SQL Server due to no space.

Comment: @X-Zero Nope, although it probably I probably should make a createdOn and createdBy as any change to the data table gets a new row in the history table. That's a nice idea though. Only 3 columns needed instead of 4.

Comment: @HardCode It's only an internal solution, so not that much use, and I have no idea how the space situation is on live. But yeah, I'll remind them to clear up some space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more a preference. Technically the `datetime` field is [larger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172424%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) than a `bit` field, but since you are required to store it anyway it does not really matter. However performance wise you can index either and get the same results. I personally think the `bit` field is redundant and use the nullable `datetime`.

Answer (score 1):

If you added the 'DeletedBy' bit a while ago, and there already records in your live database that are 'deleted', then you need to keep the bit field, as you don't have the information to enter in the 'deleted by' at this stage (I imagine).

Comment: Nope, it's still in testing, and the table was just created the other day, so I guess I can just wipe that column

Answer (score 1):

well you do need to know who deleted, so the DeletedBy column MUST stay there. Which makes the  main question: should you keep the bit column or not?

The answer is simple: no :)
I know it is just a bit columns and it doesn't occupy much but a bit multiply by a lot of rows are a lot of bits. It probably wont impact your storage of course, but there is no reason to keep redundant data in this case.

regarding the deleted = 1 fields you may have, just update the DeletedBy to something like 'system' or something that tells you that the record was deleted before the implementation of the new field

Comment: Cool, looks like the consensus is to remove the field, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are basically creating an audit trail, and it's simple to do. First, create all of your audit tables with some standard fields for audit information. For example:

```
[audit_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[audit_action] [varchar](16) NOT NULL,
[audit_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[audit_user_name] [varchar](128) NOT NULL,
--<your fields from the table being audited>
```

Default the audit_date to a value of `getdate()`. If you are using Active Directory security, default audit_user_name to a value of `suser_sname()`, otherwise you'll have to provide this in your query.

Now, create a trigger for INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE for the table to be audited. You'll write the values into your audit table. Here is an example for DELETE:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_my_table_being_audited_delete] 
   ON  [dbo].[my_table_being_audited] 
   AFTER DELETE
AS 
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO dbo.my_audit_trail_table (audit_action, --<your fields from the table being audited>)
    SELECT  'DELETE', --<your fields from the table being audited>
    FROM    deleted

END
```

Answer (score 0):

For massive tables I really don't like using soft deletes, I prefer archiving but I understand all projects are different.

I would probably just keep the 'DeletedBy' Flag on the primary table since its a little less overhead and create a DeletionLog table with 'DeletedBy' and 'Timestamp' for auditing

This would be especially beneficial in a high read environment.